# Duplicate domain in URL or Domain/AppName

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm sure this is a simple issue, but I have noticed that when I host (shared host on GoDaddy) a website the URL repeats the Application name.

Example, I have http://makedifferences.org, if I go to this its fine, but if I click a link it takes me to http://makedifferences.org/makedifferences/...

It's not just this one site, it's all my sites on GoDaddy and I think it may be the same on my sites hosted elsewhere, but I can't check them rite now.

I'm not using web deploy to deploy it, as my first thought was it had to do IIS. My guess is that it must be a setting in Publish Settings, but I played around with them and couldn't seem to get it to go away.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Garrett

**Update**

This is apparently not a mvc thing as I check on a site I have hosted at dotnet-host.com and it doesn't have this problem. So I guess it is something with my settings at Godaddy.

I have deleted the folder and setup a virtual folder and this did not fix the problem.

I have multiple site hosting through them and my domain name A record is my dedicated IP for all the sites, then in host's domain management I point the domain name to the folder the site is in.

I think this is the correct way to do this but am not sure.

**To restate my problem now that I know a bit more about it,** if I type in http://makedifferences.org/Charities/Details/3 the page loads and everything is perfect. But if I click a link on the home page to go there the url is http://makedifferences.org/makedifferences/Charities/Details/3

Thanks why I thought it was a setting in Visual Studio.

Comment: Are you precompiling your views?

Comment: No i'm not, should I be?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Your answer just provides more information to help solve the problem.  Can you paste the code in your master layout view for your home url?  The url inside of '<div class="site-title>....'.

Comment: As Pankaj Upadhyay pointed out, it is a issue with having multiple virtual folders in shared hosting, and seems to be a fairly common problem although not too many answers. Here is a link from Godaddy http://support.godaddy.com/library/removing-virtual-application-name-from-urls/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things that cause this behavior.

- Your Application is installed in a folder instead of root directory for the shared hosting.
- Your DNS settings point the domain name to this folder.

I suppose you are hosting multi-websites in shared hosting.

To get rid of this problem, you need to go in the IIS settings and set these folders as virtual directories.....Or create one for each website....And then install your application in that folder.

**UPDATE**

> This is actually not an issue related to GoDaddy shared hosting at all but an issue with hosting an ASP.NET MVC site in a virtual directory. When you use the shared hosting provided by GoDaddy you get a root folder and limitless subfolders, each of which can be its own domain, by way of virtual directory. Unfortunately, MVC’s routing engine produces URLs that will include the virtual directory name appended to the domain name.
>
> For example, let’s say you have a domain named http://www.example.com and your folder/virtual directory name is /File. If you take the MVC template project without making any modifications and upload it to your folder and then go to your url everything will look fine. You will notice the ‘Home’ and ‘About’ tabs at the top right of the page. When you click on the ‘About’ tab, since it is routed to the Home controller’s About action, you would rightly expect the URL to be www.example.com/Home/About. What you will see, though, is that the URL generated by the ActionLink method includes the name of the virtual directory. Therefore, the URL will be www.example.com/File/Home/About.

To get rid of this problem, add the following code to your **Web.config’s** `system.webServer` element

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Solution seeked from [HERE](http://blog.boyet.com/blog/blog/solution-for-asp-net-routing-on-godaddy-shared-hosting/)

Best of luck :-)

Comment: That makes sense, I have all my sites in there own directories. I've seen the virtual directories section, I will give this a try tomorrow and mark this as answered if it works! Thanks

Comment: This looks like the right track, it didn't work but I think the URL rewriting module isn't installed on my Godaddy host. I just got done working today, so I'll let you know tomorrow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Not sure why it didn't yesterday, but I was in a hurry, maybe didn't put it in the correct section, <system.webServer>

Comment: I am glad your problem's sorted out :-)

Comment: I've had the same problems, and the rewrite rule only took effect when I changed my (.net 4, iis7) app pool mode to pipeline, from classic.

Answer (score 1):

To work in all cases I used rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
            <match url=".*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And the function bellow:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            #region Godaddy shared host fix - Detect VDIR in url and remove

            //verified that HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL keeps the original url (withoud domain) before url rewrite module,
            //that way can check if the virtual directory name is at start, and remove it.
            if (Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"))
            {
                var origUrl = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"];
                var matchVdir = "/" + Myproj.Core.Constants.Environment.HostingVirtualDirectoryName + "/";

                if (origUrl.StartsWith(matchVdir))
                {
                    var urlFix = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/" + origUrl.Remove(0, matchVdir.Length);
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(urlFix);
                }
            }
            #endregion
        }
```